# bad downcasting in a derived class

Tags: c++

I am the following structure. I minimized to the shortest possible way to reproduce the error:

I have two level of derived class. I don't have any compilation error. The error is at the runtime:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF1021CF19 in base.exe: Microsoft C++
> exception: std::__non_rtti_object at memory location
> 0x00000022B9BDF458.

Is there any suggection?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Base {
public:
    int a;
    Base(int _a) : a(_a) {};
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class derivedA : public Base
{
public:
    derivedA(int _a) : Base(_a) {};
    void print() { std::cout << "dA" << std::endl; }
};

class derivedB : public derivedA
{
public:
    derivedB(int _a) : derivedA(_a) {};
    void print() { std::cout << "dB" << std::endl; }
};

void construct(std::vector<derivedA*>& da_vec) {
    da_vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<derivedA>(new derivedB(4)).get());
}

void func(derivedA& da)
{
    derivedB& db = dynamic_cast<derivedB&>(da);
    db.print();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<derivedA*> da_vec;
    construct(da_vec);
    for (auto& da : da_vec)
        func(*da);
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `da_vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<derivedA>(new derivedB(4)).get());`?  That pointer you just added gets deleted when the temporary unique_ptr is destroyed.

Comment: My main problem is within func function. when I have a reference to the derivedA and I want to get the reference to a derivedB

Comment: No it isn't. Because of the first problem you do not have a reference to derivedA, the object has been deleted before you get to that point.

Comment: Your problems start before that.  The pointer you add in construct doesn't point to anything.  The thing it pointed to was deleted as soon as the temporary `unique_ptr` you created was destroyed at the end of the full expression it was created in.

Comment: I took your code, replaced `da_vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<derivedA>(new derivedB(4)).get());` with `da_vec.push_back(new derivedB(4));` and it ran successfully. I guess you think `std::unqiue_ptr` works differently to how it actually works.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: You should be using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<derivedA>>` and `da_vec.emplace_back(new derivedB(4));` or `da_vec.push_back(std::make_unique<derivedB>(4));`. Of course you still need to add a virtual destructor to `derivedA` or `Base`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- When you `push_back` the `derivedB` base class pointer, you store a dangling pointer.

  ```
  da_vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<derivedA>(new derivedB(4)).get());
  ```

  The `unique_ptr<derivedA>` is destroyed at the end of the expression, so the pointer you got from `.get()` is "dangling", which means that it should not be dereferenced. The object it pointed at is gone.

To solve that, I suggest that you instead store `std::unique_ptr<derivedA>` in your `vector`. You also do not need to cast to `derivedB&` before calling the overridden `print` method. That's what polymorphism solves for you automatically.

Example:

```cpp
void construct(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<derivedA>>& da_vec) {
    da_vec.push_back(std::make_unique<derivedB>(4));
}

void func(derivedA& da) {
    //derivedB& db = dynamic_cast<derivedB&>(da);
    da.print();
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<derivedA>> da_vec;
    construct(da_vec);
    for (auto& da : da_vec)
        func(*da);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KoYfMjv9d)

Note: I made the `Base` destructor `virtual` too which is necessary in order to destroy objects via a base class pointer in order for *all* the destructors to be called (from most derrived to the base).

I also marked the overridden methods with `override` which is not strictly necesssary, but helps when reading the code - and it will also give you a compilation error in case you *think* you override something, but actually isn't.